# How do I display the correct UIPointerInteraction on an attachment in a UITextView?

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, uikit, uitextview

How do I show the correct UIPointerInteraction on an attachment? Using a trackpad on an iPad and hovering over an attachment in Apple Notes presents the 'circle' pointer. But in my UITextView an NSTextAttachment presents a 'line' pointer on hover. How do I configure this to be a circle?

Apple Notes Textview:

[image: Apple Notes]

My Textview:

[image]

Comment: You have to customise the pointer shape using `UIPointerShape`. See this for more https://www.raywenderlich.com/10994775-pointer-interaction-tutorial-for-ios-supporting-the-mouse-and-trackpad#toc-anchor-006

Comment: @JayachandraA How do I add that to an NSTextAttachment though? This tutorial seems to be for adding a UIPointerShape to a UIView.